# Count of items in a list in descending order

Tags: python, list

Hi I havea list like this:
`llist=['a','b','c','b','e','a','f','e','f','e','e','e','a']`
I use counter from collections and by using:

```
from collections import Counter

c=Counter(llist)

print c.items()
```

It prints `[('a', 3), ('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('e', 5), ('f', 2)]`

I want to print them in descending order like

```
   5 e
   3 a
   2 b
   2 f
   1 c
```

Comment: Use `c.most_common()`.

Comment: On a general note, you could have used sorted with `key=lambda x: -x[1]` if this just was a ordinary list of tuples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> llist = ['a','b','c','b','e','a','f','e','f','e','e','e','a']
>>> c = Counter(llist)
>>> for i,j in c.most_common():
...     print j,i
...
5 e
3 a
2 b
2 f
1 c
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`collections.Counter.most_common`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).